Terminal autocomplete (tab) not completing when changing directory up one level (cd ../)
I'm a relative Linux noob: I've worked with the bash shell for quite a while via an Ubuntu install in WSL2 on a Windows 11 machine and recently took the plunge to switch over to Linux 100%. My question is about changing directories using the terminal and using the tab autocomplete feature.
Previously when I've been navigating on Ubuntu I was able to type cd .. on the command line and then press tab which would then complete the command to be cd ../. I could have sworn that when I spun up my new install (Kali Linux) that I was able to do the same thing. But now, when I try to do this (type cd .. and then press tab to get the auto complete to change it to cd ../) this is what I see instead:

Here's the output of neofetch on my system:
OS: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling x86_64 
Host: NH50_70RA 
Kernel: 6.8.11-amd64 
Uptime: 1 day, 1 hour, 16 mins 
Packages: 3900 (dpkg) 
Shell: zsh 5.9 
Resolution: 1080x1920, 1920x1080 
DE: Plasma 5.27.10 
WM: KWin 
Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: [Plasma], Vivid-Dark-Icons [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-9750H (12) @ 4.500GHz 
GPU: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q 
Memory: 6228MiB / 31813MiB 

I feel like the different behavior is due to using bash on Ubuntu and zsh on my current setup. I found this reference on different configuration options within the .zshrc and looked through it but I wasn't able to find anything that stood out as far as what I could do to get my desired behavior. I think this is due to me not fully understanding the documentation rather than the solution not being in there.
If anyone could help me figure out what the best solution is to get this desired behavior I would greatly appreciate it.

cross-posted (and answered) on unix.stackexchange.com

For anyone looking for an answer to this question, check out this post I made over on the Unix-Linux StackExchange. At the time of writing this there are two REALLY good solutions over there that helped me get what I needed done. Here's a brief summary of what I got from over there:
From @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil's answer, adding these two lines to my .zshrc file gives the exact functionality of what I was looking for -
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs ..
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true

Many thanks to @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' for this answer and explanation.
From @Stéphane Chazelas' answer adding this to my .zshrc file produces the same behavior mostly, but I neglected to mention that I use this behavior in conjunction with a global alias, so it didn't 100% work out for me in this situation. Still an excellent solution, with an equally excellent explanation. Many thanks to @Stéphane Chazelas -
zstyle ':completion::complete:cd:*' accept-exact '(*/|)..'

Also a huge thanks to @Stéphane Chazelas for this magic-dot function, which if placed in my .zshrc file lets me accomplish basically the same functionality but in a slightly different format which I ended up liking VERY much, to the point where I think this is what I will use long term -
magic-dot() {
  if (( NUMERIC )) && [[ $LBUFFER = (|*[[:blank:]/:]) ]]; then
    LBUFFER+=..
    (( NUMERIC-- ))
  fi
    
  if [[ $LBUFFER = (|*[[:blank:]/]).. ]]; then
    repeat ${NUMERIC-1} LBUFFER+=/..
  else
    zle self-insert
  fi
}
zle -N magic-dot
bindkey . magic-dot
bindkey -M isearch . self-insert

